# Serving an image to a Spotify app?

Tags: spotify

I know everything non-dynamic is suppose to be localized but the images we use are part of our dynamic content and need to be loaded from our server.

How would we go about doing this? Since you can't reference external links?

Thanks!

Comment: You could host your image on AWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as normal HTML:

```
<img src="http://blah.com/img.jpg">
```

Make sure `blah.com` is in the "RequiredPermissions" section of your `manifest.json` and you're set.

Comment: Ahhh! `Make sure blah.com is in the "RequiredPermissions" section of your manifest.json and you're set.` was the part I was missing. Thanks!